# not able to shutdown or destroy a crashed Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, vmware-fusion, macos

I am using VMWare Fusion 10 + vagrant + High Sierra.

I provisioned a vagrant FreeBSD box with:

```
$ vagrant init freebsd/FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE
$ vagrant up --provider vmware_fusion
```

Then I made a stupid mistake, and lost control of/crashed the VM.

Both `vagrant ssh`, `vagrant halt` and `vagrant destroy default` are not working.

```
$ vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
^C==> default: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
^C==> default: Exiting immediately, without cleanup!
$ 


$ vagrant destroy default
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y
==> default: Stopping the VMware VM...
^C==> default: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to kill the actual VMWare instance.

As I am playing with the default name...

```
$ px ax | grep default | grep VMware
46826   ??  Ss     2:09.49 /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vmx -s vmx.noUIBuildNumberCheck=TRUE -# product=1;name=vmrun;version=1.17.0;buildnumber=7520154;licensename=VMware Fusion for Mac OS;licenseversion=10.0; -@ duplex=3;msgs=ui /Users/ruiribeiro/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_fusion/c38ba960-54c2-4bf6-ba61-0388f47da5d9/vagrant.vmx

$ kill -9 46826
```

Then after killing it, finally you manage to clean/destroy it successfully:

```
$ vagrant destroy default
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y
==> default: Deleting the VM...
$
```