# tcpdump crashing Vagrant box in VMWare Fusion

Tags: osx, vagrant, vmware-fusion

I deployed both a FreeBSD 10.3 and a OpenBSD 6.2 VM in VMWare Fusion 10 + Vagrant + High Sierra.

However, they both hang when running:

```
sudo tcpdump -n port 53
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, from what I found on this ticket [tcpdump in toolbox causes a headless vagrant (vmware_fusion) CoreOS instance to hang #1377](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1377), it is a VMWare Fusion bug.

> It sounds like this is a VMware Fusion bug, and I'm going to go out on
>   a limb and assume it's been fixed by now. Please reopen if any of that
>   appears to be incorrect.

Also in this ticket, it is said the workarounds that work for being able to do a promiscuous `tcpdump` is either doing:

```
sudo touch '/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/promiscAuthorized'
```

or:

> Open “VMware Fusion > Preferences”, click on the “Network” tab, click
>   the lock in the bottom left corner, authenticate as an admin user, and
>   uncheck the “require authentication to enter promiscuous mode” box.

or:

> Set `ethernet.promptForPromisc = FALSE` in the VM’s .vmx file, where
>   Number corresponds to the ethernet adapter the VM is trying to
>   `tcpdump`.

(Yes, I understand the security implications)

Effectively, for testing, after touching `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/promiscAuthorized`, I launched the VMs, and they to not hang anymore when running a `tcpdump`.

I will in the future use the solution of editing the .vmx and setting `ethernet.promptForPromisc = FALSE`, for not affecting all VMs with the `promiscAuthorized` setting.

See also [not able to shutdown or destroy a crashed Vagrant box](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427969/not-able-to-shutdown-or-destroy-a-crashed-vagrant-box)